# Why byte array need to convert to hex decimal string after encrypting the text

Tags: java, cryptography, arrays, hex

I have seen some examples on encryption .Almost in all examples after getting the digest message , we are getting the byte array.After that they are converting to hex decimal string.Is it mandatory to convert into hex decimal string.Or is there any another way ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data passed as raw `binary data` can easily be corrupted in transit, and a different systems may interpret some of the bytes in the binary data as control characters with unintended results.

You should always encode the ciphertext data using, say, `base64` or `hexadecimal encoding`. The resulting text can be easily transferred without loss of integrity and can then be decoded back into binary on the destination system before decryption.

`One byte is an 8-bit value` which can be represented in `hexadecimal`. A byte array is a series of hexadecimal values.

Comment: is this applicable even within the same system?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure how you mean, a byte[] as well as hex or even simple string conversion are all just some useful representations of a digest depending on context used. If you want to make it easy to use in a GUI / browser i.e. for human usage, byte[] won't work so the next more compact form is hex as 4bytes make one char. so it's pretty compact and easy to work with.

Then there is web usage where often you see them base64 encoded as well to ensure constant length